# Delete the last char of a String if it is an ","

Tags: java, string, char

So I'm having a String and after doing some operations on it, it happens that i have an "," too much in the end. Now how can i delete this last "," only if it really is an `","`?

My Input String is:

```
String input =",w84,w41,w56,w170,w56,w41,w84,/,,w24,w40,w17,w40,w48,,/,,,w16,w16,w16,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,b1,b1,b1,,,/,,b3,b130,b17,b130,b129,,/,b69,b146,b131,b170,b131,b146,b69,";
```

and the output is:

```
,w84,w41,w56,w170,w56,w41,,w84/,,w24,w40,w17,w40,w48,,/,,,w16,,w16,,,/,,,,w32,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,,,,,,/,,,b1,b1,b1,,,/,,b3,b130,b17,b130,b129,,/,b69,b146,b131,b170,b131,b146,b69,,
```

now how do i get rid of this last ","?

Comment: what have you tried so far? and how do you get that output?

Comment: Possibly the wrong question. Chances are you'd rather want to change your *operations* to avoid creating the extra comma

Answer (score 1):

You can use replaceAll with regex :

```
 input = input.replaceAll(",+$", "");
```

**Output**

```
...131,b146,b69
```

---

If you want to keep only one `,` in the end if there are multiple, then instead you have to replace with `,` instead of empty :

```
input = input.replaceAll(",+$", ",");
```

**Output**

```
...131,b146,b69,
```

Comment: there is a flaw in the solution. it still should end with ,

Comment: @Stultuske ok, I don't understand it well then, I put another solution :)

Comment: your solution seemed well, but like most it didn't take into account it can have an actual last , as char. IMO, the fix shouldn't be changing the output, it should be avoiding having that additional , in the output

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid regexpr...

```
if (str != null && str.endsWith(',')) {
    return str.substring(0, str.length() -1);
}
return str;
```

or you could use the apache commins library and avoid the null-check

```
if (StringUtils.endsWith(str, ',') {
    return str.substring(0, str.length() -1);
}
return str;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String method(String str) {
if (str != null && str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == ',') {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
}
return str;
}
```

This method removes the last character if it is a comma. If you want to remove ALL commas at the end, you can change this method:

```
public String method(String str) {
while (str != null && str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == ',') {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
}
return str;
}
```

Comment: there is a flaw in the solution. it still should end with ,, your code doesn't guarantee that. better way is to avoid putting the last ,

Comment: @NivedithaKarmegam I'm not the OP, so I'm not sure why you are asking me. This solution makes sure that each time the last , is removed. But what if he has output that doesn't have an additional but a correct , as last char?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Code only answers are highly discouraged. Please edit your answer and provide a brief explanation for what it solves, otherwise this answer may be voted for deletion on a review queue.

Comment: The first method, like the aforementioned Nicktar and Shivam Mohan, removes only one last comma. The question does not say that you want to remove all last commas. I added code that removes all the last commas

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code to remove the last character from the string if it is `,`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String string = args[0];
        /* Please handle cases where string is empty or not defined */
        if(string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == ','){
            string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
        }
      System.out.println(string);
    }
```